# Trying to understand module and package imports better

Tags: python, import, module, package

I am trying to better understand how Python identifies and defines modules from packages.

Looking at tkinter as a common example when I look at the files provided under anaconda>Lib>tkinter there is no tkinter.py file and if I do a text search on the files in the tkinter directory I do not see how tkinter as a module is defined and yet I am able to import it and use it. Would appreciate an explanation to understand what I am missing? Maybe it is defined in .pyc files?

Comment: There should be `tkinter` folder inside `Lib`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't use anaconda; mine is just the standard installation from python.org. My `Lib` directory does have a `tkinter` folder within it -- *but* there is no `tkinter.py`. As with any package there is a `__init__.py` file within that directory and in that file is the following:

```py
import _tkinter # If this fails your Python may not be configured for Tk
```

This suggests that my Python is supposed to be built with a C library implementation of `_tkinter` that provides the necessary support.

**Are you sure there is no `tkinter` *directory*?**

**Update**

When you `import tkinter`, you are importing a *package* in this case because `tkinter` is a directory that includes a  `__init__.py` file. And what happens as a result is that `__init__.py` gets loaded and executed. The global names in that file become attributes of the `tkinter` module. For example, function `_join` in that file can be accessed as `tkinter._join`. But also because there is an `import sys` statement in that file, you can even access `tkinter.sys`.  Or if you prefer you can say, `from tkinter import sys`.

But you can also say `from tkinter import messagebox`. Why? True, there is no `messagebox` definition in `__init__.py` but there is a `messagebox.py` file in the `tkinter` directory and that is how other submodules can be loaded.

The `__init__.py` file, which must be present in the directory for all packages and is what defines a directory as being a package, contains code to initialize a package when the package name is imported. It may contain code to import certain commonly used submodules of the package. Many times the file is just empty, but needs to be present.

Comment: Thx. Yes there is a tkinter directory but no file. I also looked at the __init__.py file for this and saw the reference to _tkinter. However __init__.py itself imports tkinter. So where is the original definition of tkinter? Is it inferred from the directory name 'tkinter' or does it exist elsewhere?

Comment: @Jez Directory name

Comment: See my update to the answer. Yes, it is inferred from the directory name.

Comment: @Booboo Thank you for the answers, got it now